# void* to pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

Normally when calling a dynamically loaded function I usually do a standard straight cast:

```
typedef int (*GenericFn)(); // matches x86 FARPROC, minus explicit calling convention
typedef bool (*DesiredFn)(int,int);

GenericFn address = GetProcAddress(module, "MyFunction");
DesiredFn target = reinterpret_cast<DesiredFn>(address);
```

Today I did something a little different (and braindead).

```
DesiredFn target = nullptr;

void* temp = static_cast<void*>(&target); // pointer to function pointer
GenericFn* address = static_cast<GenericFn*>(temp);
*address = GetProcAddress(module, "MyFunction"); // supposedly valid?

// temp is declared void* because a void** cannot be cast to GenericFn* without
// first doing a void** -> void* conversion

assert(target == MyFunction); // true on VC10, presumably GCC
```

---

My questions:

1. Is the behavior of a `void*` (note: **not** a `void**`) to an object pointer type well-defined?
2. Why does the compiler allow `static_cast<void*>` on a `void**`?
3. Why am I stupid enough to try this?
4. Do you see anything else that's wrong with this example?

I've since decided to use method #1 again because of code clarity (and because I know it's supposed to work). I'm still interested in why method #2 worked though :).

---

### In case you're wondering (about my explanation)

Today I was removing `<windows.h>` dependencies in several public interfaces, and rather than redeclare `FARPROC` like I should have, I experimentally changed my `FARPROC` return-type function to instead accept a `void*` output parameter (I know, it should probably have been a `void**`).

```
// implemented in some library cpp file
void detail::FunctionResolve(std::string export, void* output)
{
    FARPROC* address = static_cast<FARPROC*>(output);
    *address = GetProcAddress(...);
}

// header-defined interface class
template<typename F>
class RuntimeFunction {
    F* target;

    void SetFunction(std::string export) {
        // old: this->target = reinterpret_cast<F*>(detail::FunctionResolve(...));
        // new:
        detail::FunctionResolve(export, static_cast<void*>(&this->target));
    }
};
```

Comment: "Why does the compiler allow `static_cast<void*>` on a `void**`?"  Nowhere do you do this in the code that you present.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to use void* on functions. Try void(*)(void) instead.

Comment: I explained void** in the code comments. I also explained the (data) pointer to function-pointer; I never said it was a function pointer. And addressing a function pointer stored in a temporary does not return a function pointer; this isn't at compile-time. Do you know what Kernel32.GetProcAddress is?

Comment: @JasonWoof: the Win32 API requires that cast when using `GetProcAddress()`.  The cast is non-standard, but then again neither is the Win32 API!

Comment: out of curiosity, you're casting your F** to a void * before you call FunctionResolve, then cast it to a FARPROC* before you assign it, why not just make the function arguments a FARPROC * and cast it once?

Comment: Or even better, make it a template function which takes a T* and casts it to a FARPROC* inside the function so still only one cast, but the callers don't have to do it.

Comment: If anyone is confused by my last post, the guy I responded to deleted his comment.

Comment: @MerickOWA: That would expose the FARPROC declaration to the public interface, because SetFunction must be implemented as a template function in the header. I also can't implement FunctionResolve in the header, because it's long and would be instantiated repeatedly (and it does platform specific exception handling/calls/etc).

Comment: @andre-caron: I understand the need to cast, but surely you don't need to cast it to a void*. If for some reason you can't or don't want to cast directly to the type you want, I suggest casting to void(*)(void) first, not void*.

Comment: @JasonWoof: That's what I did immediately after writing this code snippet. (Which is what I meant by adding my own FARPROC typedef.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef int (*GenericFn)(); // matches x86 FARPROC, minus explicit calling convention
typedef bool (*DesiredFn)(int,int);

DesiredFn target = nullptr;

void* temp = static_cast<void*>(&target); // pointer to function pointer
```

There's nothing wrong here, but the cast is unnecessary. A pointer to any object (a pointer to a function is an object) can be converted to a pointer to `void` without a cast. e.g.

```
void* temp = &target;
```

---

```
GenericFn* address = static_cast<GenericFn*>(temp);
```

You can convert from a pointer to `void` to a pointer to any object type but the results are only defined if you cast a value the was converted to a `void*` back to the original type that it was converted from. Technically, only a `static_cast<DesiredFn*>(temp)` would have a well defined result.

```
*address = GetProcAddress(module, "MyFunction"); // supposedly valid?
```

This isn't technically correct as you have lied about the type of the value that you assigned to `address` so `address` isn't pointing to an object that matches its type information.

Having said all that, in many implementations function pointers are all represented in the same way and any cast and conversions don't have any effect on the value that is actually stored. So long as you call the function throught a pointer that actually matches the type of the pointer you won't have any problems.

After all, you have to rely on your implementation's behaviour of `reinterpret_cast` and `GetProcAddress` for the original method to work at all, but - as you say -  I would recommend sticking with the `reinterpret_cast` approach in this case as it is clearer what is going on.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of comment I was looking for originally :). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter because void* and void** are the same size.  You're just changing the type.  Why not just cast directly to the type you want?

```
DesiredFn target = 
    reinterpret_cast<DesiredFn>(GetProcAddress(module, "MyFunction"));
```

Comment: You simply re-posted my own example. I (badly?) explained why I didn't do that at first in the bottom half of my post. I would have had to declare a custom FARPROC typedef, because the class encapsulating the function pointer is generic ala std::function.

Comment: Apologies, thought I'd take a stab at it.  ;)  I read it again, and maybe I'm not sure exactly what's being asked.  But yes, void* to an object is well defined.  And static_cast assumes you know what your doing.  Personally, I'd change FARPROC to void*, but I'm not sure it matters.

Comment: I updated the bottom code example. Maybe that makes it more clear? I wouldn't have been able to return void* without casting a function pointer (or temporary) to void*... both very bad ideas.